# Visualforce Composition ignores template styling

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-template

The following VF page entitled TemplatePage looks fine when opened:

```
<apex:page>
    <head>
        <style>
        .mainDiv { ... }
        </style>
    </head>

    <div class="mainDiv">...</div>
</apex:page>
```

The following page does not look correct (styles are ignored):

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:composition template="TemplatePage"/>
</apex:page>
```

Why are template styles gone and how can I preserve the styles?

Comment: Can you please paste more about your page and css, please? I tried with your code and color: red in the css and it works for me in the main page

Comment: This was due to different API versions for the 2 pages. Apparently they need to be on the same version. Your reply prompted me to create the entire thing from scratch only to see it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The TemplatePage was on API 26.0 while the overriding page was on version 34.0. Setting both to the same version (either one) made it work!